# Setting devise routes with locales failing on redirect after authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

So I've been trying to set my routes for devise as follows:

```
scope '(:locale)' do
  devise_for :users, skip: [:registrations]
  resources :questions
end
```

However when I authenticate in my controller, when you're not signed in devise redirects you to `localhost:3000/users/sign_in`.

What I expect to happen would it to redirect me to `localhost:3000/en/users/sign_in`. What am I doing wrong or what way is there around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out you can't set the routes in your scope, but rather need to set them manually. At least that's what's worked for me.

```
devise_for :users, skip: [:sessions]
as :user do
  get ':locale/login' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
  post ':locale/login' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
  delete ':locale/logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
end

# your normal scope without devise_for in it
scope '(:locale)' do
  resources :questions
end
```

After this the redirects work as expected.